# get sum of column values from SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query and I am trying to get sum of values from Column2.

```
SELECT c.column1, c.column2
FROM table1 c 
LEFT JOIN table2 d ON d.column_id = c.column_id
Group by c.column1

column1         column2   
------------------------
survey_name1     10       
survey_name2     20
```

I would like to have a 3 rd column with sum of column2(i.e 10+20=30).I am not sure this is possible. Please suggest if there is any alternative solution available.

```
column1         column2  column3 
-------------------------------
survey_name1     10       30
survey_name2     20       30
```

Comment: Are you after `SELECT  c.column1, c.column2, (c.column1 + c.column2) as Column3` ??

Comment: No. I would like to have sum of column2 values.

Comment: Why do you want this as a third column? Why don't you just do a second query using SUM function on column 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a very good reason for having the exact same sum of values in each row, I'd strongly recommend that you use a second query to get the sum of column2 values instead:

```
SELECT  
  SUM(c.column2)
FROM table1 c 
    LEFT JOIN table2 d ON d.column_id = c.column_id
Group by c.column1
```

If that doesn't work for you please give more details on why you want sum on each rows.

**EDIT:**

If you *really* need sum on each row, you could cross join your original query with the one above. But really I can't think of a good reason to do this.

Comment: I agree with you. Thank you.